# Image captured from camera not displayed in imageview in lollipop

Tags: image, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera-intent

I am developing an Android application where the user activates the camera on button click and set that image into an ImageView.

This was working flawlessly until yesterday. But after I updated my Android version to 5.0.1, the ImageView is not displaying anything. But the surprising thing is that, it still works for lower versions.

I have gone through several websites, but still no result.

Here is my code snippet:

```
//Button Click action  
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // start camera activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {  

        // get bundle
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    }   
}
```

Comment: No one is facing this type of problems?? Amazing !!

Comment: I faces the same brother , did you get any solution ?

Comment: i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Following code will take image either from gallery or camrea and its working on all version you can copy the code for camrea only

```
  private File photoFile = null;
        public void selectImage() {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                final TextView camrea= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                final TextView lib= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                final TextView cancel= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text2);


     camrea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent() ;
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            lib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 200);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 300);
                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }



         private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission = new MarshMallowPermission(this);
            if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
                marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
            } else {
                if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
                    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
                } else {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        // Create the File where the photo should go
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                        }
                        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            //Log.d("Uri","Activity started");
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void Setimage(Uri imguri) {
            //you can set ur image here using uri
            }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,/* prefix */
            ".jpg",       /* suffix */
            storageDir    /* directory */);
}

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
      if (requestCode == 100) {
            if("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(Uri.fromFile(photoFile).getAuthority()))
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "File Not On Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
               Setimage(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }



        } else if (requestCode == 200) {
            mIsImageUploadUri=Uri.parse(getPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(data.getData().toString())));
            final Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(getPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(),data.getData()));
             //Log.d(TAG,"Uri"+ selectedImage.toString());
            if("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(selectedImage.getAuthority()))
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "File Not On Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {

                 Setimage(data.getData());

            }

        }else if (requestCode == 300) {
            final Uri originalUri = data.getData();
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            //noinspection ResourceType
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
             Log.d(TAG,"Uri"+ originalUri.toString());
            if("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(originalUri.getAuthority()))
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "File Not On Device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {

                Setimage(originalUri);
            }
        }
    }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public static String getPathFromURI(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
            final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    }
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
                    Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
                    final String selection = "_id=?";
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                            split[1]
                    };
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
        public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
        public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
```